# Mockito Unit Test void function in a class

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I am fairly new to Mockito. I am not sure how to test the void function emitcount() or to actually test the class to 100%?

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class MetricsFactoryProvider {
private MetricsFactory metricsHelper;

public void emitCount(final String metricName, final double metricCount, final long startTime) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(metricName)) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        Metrics metrics = metricsHelper.newMetrics();
        metrics.addDate("StartTime", startTime);
        metrics.addCount(metricName, metricCount, Unit.ONE);
        metrics.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw some exception();
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far

```
public class MetricsFactoryProviderTest {
@Mock
Metrics metrics;

@Mock
MetricsFactory metricsHelper;

public void testemitCountfromMetricsFactoryProvider() {

    metricsHelper = new MetricsHelper();
    Metrics metrics = metricsHelper.newMetrics();
    metrics.addDate("StartTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
    metrics.addCount("some", 1, Unit.ONE);

    MetricsFactoryProvider metricsFactoryProvider = new MetricsFactoryProvider(metrics.getMetricsFactory());
    metricsFactoryProvider.emitCount("some metric name",1,System.currentTimeMillis());

    Assert.assertNotNull(metricsFactoryProvider);

}
```

How do I test emitfunction? My thought process

1. donothing(when(metricsFactoryProvider.emitfunction(pass args)))
2. Or Do I have to use ArgumentCaptor() ? How do I verify that the function emitfunction is called and metricsFactoryProvider object has correct data?

Comment: Hint: that **preview** window exists for a reason. To make sure that *you* check the formatting of your input prior posting. You want us to spend our time to help you - so you please the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your input!

Comment: Sorry I rectified it

Comment: No prob. Just remember that for the future ... and beyond that: don't forget about accepting answers at some point - to show future readers that the problem is solved. At least consider upvoting helpful answers at some point ... now that you reached that level ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This here:

```
@Mock
Metrics metrics;
```

together with

```
Metrics metrics = new MetricsHelper().newMetrics();
```

simply doesn't make **any** sense. Your test class defines a mocked Metrics object - but then create *another* real metrics objects which you then pass to your class under test.

It is pretty simple: when you can *verify* the expected behavior using a *real* object - then do that. Otherwise, you use a mock.

And then you could do things like

```
MetricsFactoryProvider underTest = new MetricsFactoryProvider(mockedHelper);
underTest.emit(...);
verify(mockedHelper).add(eq("Start Date"), any());
```

just for example. In that sense: don't try to learn mocking by trial and error. It is too complicated for that. Instead: read and follow a good tutorial, like this [one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html).

But just to give a short hint here: there are **two** different cases for using mocks.

```
Whatever mockedFoo = mock(Whatever.class);
when(mockedFoo.bar()).thenReturn("something else");
UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest(mockedFoo);
assertThat(underTest.foo(), is("something else"));
```

The above uses a "mocking specification" so that the class under test can **do** its job. You need to control the mock to do something inside your test. Compare that to:

```
Whatever mockedFoo = mock(Whatever.class);
UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest(mockedFoo);
assertThat(underTest.foo(), is("something else"));
verify(mockedFoo).bar("expected"parm");
```

In this case, you want *check* that a certain expected call happened.

Comment: If you have a new question, please consider to ask a real, full question. Dont comment on some answer to ask something that hasnt anything to do with the question/answer you comment on.